# Deriving the equation of motion of a pendulum from energy conservation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The kinetic energy of a simple pendulum is:
$$K=\frac{1}{2}mL^2(\frac{d\theta}{dt})^2$$

The potential energy of the pendulum is:
$$U=mgL(1-cos\theta)$$

The total energy of the pendulum is therefore:
$$E=K+U=K=\frac{1}{2}mL^2(\frac{d\theta}{dt})^2+mgL(1-cos\theta)$$

The total energy of the system is constant, therefore:
$$\frac{dE}{dt}=0$$

I am given to understand that taking the derivative of the total energy with respect to $t$ should allow me to rearrage for the equation of motion of a pendulum,
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\frac{g}{L}sin\theta=0$$

but I don't see how.  Taking the derivative of the third equation returns $0$, which isn't very useful.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Both theta and its derivative depend on time, so when they are differentiated, they can't be treated as constants. So differentiating the third equation should give some non-trivial info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your third equation
$$E=K+U=K=\frac{1}{2}mL^2(\frac{d\theta}{dt})^2+mgL(1-\cos\theta)$$
after derivation with respect to $t$ it becomes
$$0=mL^2\frac{d\theta}{dt}\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+mgL\sin\theta\frac{d\theta}{dt}$$
and divided by $mL^2\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ you can get what you want.

Comment: The small hiccup (usually not important for physics, but quite important in math) is that the division is invalid when the angular velocity is (instantaneously) zero.

Comment: Yeah, and since the pendulum gets zero torque at the lowest position, I should have deduced it more precisely like $0=mL^2\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+mgL\sin\theta$ or $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=0$ if no other information was given.

Comment: @Jordan variation calc taking $,K-U$ functional is also possible